# Passing a missing argument in R

Tags: r

I'm writing a function in R that, among other things, subsets a data frame based on a vector of column names. I'm trying to exploit the default behavior of `[.data.frame` which will return all columns if the 'j' argument is missing. Is there a way to pass a missing argument through my wrapper function? Here's a bare bones example:

```
fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, columns){
    lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x) x[,columns])
}
```

If I do not specify a value for columns, I get an error when passing it to the `[` function: "columns argument is missing, with no default".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set a default for columns such that if nothing is supplied it grabs all of the columns.  Using TRUE should work

```
fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, columns = TRUE){
    lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x) x[,columns])
}

# As Chase points out it is probably more prudent to add drop=FALSE as a parameter
fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, columns = TRUE, drop = FALSE){
    lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x) x[, columns, drop = drop])
}
```

Comment: Doh - should have thought of this...I tried setting the default to `NULL` and `NA`, but that didn't work. I still think OP should consider adding `drop = FALSE` to ensure result is always a data.frame if that's what they intend.

Comment: You should set this up as `lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x, columns) x[,columns], columns = columns)` so R isn't having to go looking for `columns`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different tack is to not have an anonymous function and call `[` directly.

```
fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, columns = TRUE, drop = TRUE){
    lapply(listOfDataFrames, `[`, , j = columns, drop = drop)
}
```

Note that the blank space between the two `,` is **important** as this represents the space for `i` the row index. By leaving this missing we get the same behaviour as `df[ , columns]`. I also set `drop = TRUE` as that is the default for `[` so the fun maintains behaviour.

With the same data from @Chase's Answer:

```
## Sample data
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
listOfDataFrames <- list(df1, df2)

fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames)
fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames, 2)
fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames, 2, drop = FALSE)
```

Giving

```
> fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames)
[[1]]
            x1          x2          x3
1  -1.98347150 -0.50473182  0.56554491
2  -0.19597580  0.41004825 -0.35646296
3   0.81792146 -0.07646175 -2.02534426
4  -0.01903514  0.70687248 -0.25373188
5  -0.49233958  0.42497338 -0.15647100
6   0.62296268  1.88127659  0.41952414
7  -0.27260248 -2.59046602 -1.99294060
8   1.46344557  1.44803287  0.08634971
9   0.62207040  1.78290849 -0.17131320
10 -1.05730518 -0.45478467  1.15346862

[[2]]
            x1          x2          x3
1  -1.98347150 -0.50473182  0.56554491
2  -0.19597580  0.41004825 -0.35646296
3   0.81792146 -0.07646175 -2.02534426
4  -0.01903514  0.70687248 -0.25373188
5  -0.49233958  0.42497338 -0.15647100
6   0.62296268  1.88127659  0.41952414
7  -0.27260248 -2.59046602 -1.99294060
8   1.46344557  1.44803287  0.08634971
9   0.62207040  1.78290849 -0.17131320
10 -1.05730518 -0.45478467  1.15346862

> fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames, 2)
[[1]]
 [1] -0.50473182  0.41004825 -0.07646175  0.70687248  0.42497338  1.88127659
 [7] -2.59046602  1.44803287  1.78290849 -0.45478467

[[2]]
 [1] -0.50473182  0.41004825 -0.07646175  0.70687248  0.42497338  1.88127659
 [7] -2.59046602  1.44803287  1.78290849 -0.45478467

> fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames, 2, drop = FALSE)
[[1]]
            x2
1  -0.50473182
2   0.41004825
3  -0.07646175
4   0.70687248
5   0.42497338
6   1.88127659
7  -2.59046602
8   1.44803287
9   1.78290849
10 -0.45478467

[[2]]
            x2
1  -0.50473182
2   0.41004825
3  -0.07646175
4   0.70687248
5   0.42497338
6   1.88127659
7  -2.59046602
8   1.44803287
9   1.78290849
10 -0.45478467
```

Comment: Nice.  I feel silly for not thinking of this - it's definitely a cleaner approach in my opinion.

Comment: @Dason I don't think this (my answer) will be useful in the more-general case the OP has in mind as the subset is just one step of some longer computation. But thought it worth sticking in here in case someone wants the simple subset case.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a hack, but setting up the second argument as `...` allows for this behaviour:

```
#Sample data
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
listOfDataFrames <- list(df1, df2)


fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, ...){
  lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x) x[,...])
}

> fixDataFrames(listOfDataFrames)
[[1]]
           x1         x2         x3
1  -1.7475354 -1.3444461  0.2049100
2   0.1451163  1.4396253  0.5885829
...
[[2]]
           x1         x2         x3
1  -1.7475354 -1.3444461  0.2049100
2   0.1451163  1.4396253  0.5885829
```

You might also want to add `, drop = FALSE` to prevent the data.frame from being coerced into a vector if a single column is selected.

Comment: I don't think that is quite right. Shouldn't you at least have: `function(x, ...)` and really `...` needs to be supplied to the `...` of `lapply` so it passes it on to the anonymous function.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - That's what I initially tested, though setting up the function as you describe above resulted in nothing being passed through to the anonymous function.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, but the anonymous function is within the "main" function's environment, isn't it? So, wouldn't that be sufficient to access the `...`? (maybe I misunderstand, but I had to clarify!)

Comment: @Chase Yes - passing in `...` in this context is difficult and not what is needed really. It could be done with judicious processing  of `...` but easier to call `[` directly.

Comment: @Arun Yes, but in functional languages one normally passes in all arguments used/needed by the function so it doesn't have to go off finding something that matches the object name it is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but try:

```
fixDataFrames <- function(listOfDataFrames, columns){
    lapply(listOfDataFrames, function(x) 
        if (missing(columns)) {
            columns <- 1:ncol(x)
        }
        x[,columns]
    )
}
```

Comment: It might make more sense to move the if(missing...) stuff outside of the function and instead define columns for the missing case before the lapply statement.  Then you're only doing it once instead of for every element in the list.

Comment: @Dason - what if the individual dfs have different numbers of columns? Of course the code should then be `seq_len(ncol(x))`, but that is quibbling...

Comment: but dason it's a list of dataframes that would imply a list of columns  hence a ened for passing index values to `lapply` or using `mapply`.  I assumed (but maybe wrongly) that the column numbers may vary.

Comment: I guess that could make sense.  I guess from the format of the function I just assumed that the dataframes would have a similar structure.  Otherwise I would expect columns to be a list as well but it didn't seem like that was the case from the OP.  But you're right - if `ncols` varies then we would probably want to recalculate it for each df

Comment: This was close to my initial approach but I thought it a little too...verbose. And yes, all dfs have the same structure, so columns is the same for all